# JOI validation string fails on , and

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

I use [joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) for validation and am trying to validate a **comments** textarea content in the following way:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    firstName: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
    lastName: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
    company: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
    comments: Joi.string().alphanum().min(30).max(1500).required(),
    email: Joi.string().email().required()
});
```

However, if anyone enters a comma or fullstop, the validation fails. How can I add those exceptions to the validation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you probably would want to allow people to anything in the comments field, I would simply leave out the `alphanum` for the comments validation, like this:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    firstName: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
    lastName: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
    company: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),

    // note: no alphanum here
    comments: Joi.string().min(30).max(1500).required(),

    email: Joi.string().email().required()
});
```

If you really, really must have comments that contain only letters, numbers, commas and periods, you could resort to using the [regex](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.0.2/API.md#stringregexpattern-name--options) rule:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    // ...
    comments: Joi.string().regex(/^[,. a-z0-9]+$/).required(),
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex that includes alphanumeric characters plus comma. I have no idea what you mean by *fullstop* btw.

```
Joi.string().regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9, ]*$/, 'Alphanumerics, space and comma characters').min(3).max(30).required()
```

Note this will literally only match the characters in ranges a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and the space and comma characters. Anything else (like the period character, brackets, parenthesis?) you would need to add.

Source is the [Joi API docs](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.0.2/API.md#stringregexpattern-name--options).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Regex syntax for the same

`comments: Joi.string().regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9,. ]*$/).min(3).max(30).required()`